# Use of BingMapsTask on WP8 and WP7 - different result

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

So I've been using the BingMapsTask since wp7 to show a specific location that the user has selected in the app.
But since wp8, the behaviour has changed! How can we still use the BingMapsTaks?

To run this code, be sure to change your region settings to BELGIUM - DUTCH. When you do this, the code will show correct location in WP7 emulator, but on WP8 it won't! ( see images for settings and result )
[Demo app on GitHub](https://github.com/Depechie/BingMapsTaksPhone)

```
GeoCoordinate location = new GeoCoordinate(51.40205, 4.46802);

BingMapsTask task = new BingMapsTask();
task.Center = location;
task.SearchTerm = location.ToString();
task.ZoomLevel = 9;
task.Show();
```

[image: Region settings]

GOOD

[image: Good result]

BAD

[image: Bad result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've seen something similar with BingMapsDirectionTask: It only worked when phone's regional settings were set to US. The solution with that was to set current thread's culture before launching the task:

```
            BingMapsDirectionsTask Direction = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
            LabeledMapLocation start = new LabeledMapLocation(...);
            LabeledMapLocation End = new LabeledMapLocation(...);
            Direction.Start = start;
            Direction.End = End;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Direction.Show();
```

(More info about this issue for example [from MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0aeda35f-053c-463c-8719-76c149f5699d/bingmapsdirectionstask-not-working-without-region-format-set-to-english?forum=wpdevelop).)

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work with BingMapsTask. The issue is with the SearchTerm: If you remove that, the map seems to be centered correctly but it doesn't show the PushPin.

Do you know the address of the selected coordinate? If you do, you could change the SearchTerm to that address and it should work.

For example this one should show the correct location:

```
        GeoCoordinate location = new GeoCoordinate(51.40205, 4.46802);

        BingMapsTask task = new BingMapsTask();
        task.Center = location;
        task.SearchTerm = "Noordeind 51, 2920 Kalmthout, Belgia";
        task.ZoomLevel = 9;
        task.Show();
```

Comment: I confirm: If you want BingMapsDirectionTask to use the coordinate you supply, you must indeed not include a search term. Furthermore, you must temporarily set the culture to the invariant one (en reset it back afterwards, typically in a finally block). That was the case on WP7 as well. So unfortunaltely, this doesn't answer OP's question directly.

Comment: I can live with the fact that we need to use BingMapsDirectionTask, even though I think it's a bug in the OS that we can't pass a normal Geocoordinate as search term :( ( we can in wp7 and EN-US wp8 )

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is Windows Phone 8, I'd advise to use the MapsTask instead as it is prefered in WP8!

Also, instead of `ToString()` try instead with `ToString(CultureInfo.InvarianCulture)`

Comment: Nope... not possible to use the ToString on GeoCoordinate with the CultureInfo!

Comment: Added culture test also on the GitHub now, by ToString on Latitude and Longitude instead of GeoCoordinate, without any success!

Answer (score 0):

For WP7, use BingMapsTask, for WP8 use MapsTask.

Comment: No difference... github now uses Cimbalino too